# How can I scan for a bluetooth device in a script?

Tags: bash, bluetooth

I know I can use `bluetoothctl scan on` to scan for a device. But when I want to use this in a bash script, this is not usable, as this command never ends.

I would like a command that scans for say 30 seconds and prints whatever it found to standard out.

Is that possible with `bluetoothctl` or any other tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `--timeout <seconds>` to use it in non interactive mode e.g:

`bluetoothctl --timeout 20 scan on`

It will stop the scan after 20 sec

Comment: Thanks, `bluetoothctl` has no `man` page, where did you get this information from?

Comment: bluetoothctl --help